# Improving and optimizing Tic-Tac-Toe game written in Python 3

Tags: python, optimization, game, python-3.x

I've been teaching myself Python3 for about a week now and I decided to put my skills to the test by writing a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game. Here is what I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random

board = [0]*9

def resetBoard():
    for index, i in enumerate(board):
        board[index] = 0

def printBoard():
    counter = 0
    s = ""
    print("|-----|-----|-----|")
    for index, i in enumerate(board):
        s += "|  "
        if(board[index] == 0):
            s += str(index)
        if(board[index] == 1):
            s+= "x"
        if(board[index] == 2):
            s += "o"
        s += "  "
        counter += 1
        if(counter == 3):
            s += "|"
            print(s)
            print("|-----|-----|-----|")
            s = ""
            counter = 0

def getPlayers():
    return input("1 or 2 Players?")

def moveSquare(xOro, ai):
    square = 0
    flag = 0
    while(board[square] != 0 or flag == 0):
        if(ai == 0):
            if(xOro == 1):
                square = eval(input("Choose a square to place X: "))
            if(xOro == 2):
                square = eval(input("Choose a square to place O: "))
        if(ai == 1):
            square = random.randint(0, 8)
        flag = 1
    board[square] = xOro
    print("\n\n")

def checkForWin():
    if(board[0] == board[1] and board[1] == board[2] and board[2] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[3] == board[4] and board[4] == board[5] and board[5] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[6] == board[7] and board[7] == board[8] and board[8] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[0] == board[3] and board[3] == board[6] and board[6] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[1] == board[4] and board[4] == board[7] and board[7] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[2] == board[5] and board[5] == board[8] and board[8] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[0] == board[4] and board[4] == board[8] and board[8] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[2] == board[4] and board[4] == board[6] and board[6] != 0):
        return 1
    for index, i in enumerate(board):
        if(i  == 0):
            break
        if(index == 8):
            return 2
    return 0

def gameOver():
    return eval(input("\nPress 0 and then ENTER to play again!"))

# Main
random.seed()
quit = 0
while(quit == 0):
    players = 0
    win = 0
    while(players != 1 and players != 2):
        players = eval(getPlayers())
    resetBoard()
    game = 0 #game = 1 when game is finished
    while(game == 0): #game loop
        printBoard()
        moveSquare(1, 0)
        game = checkForWin()
        if(game > 0):
            win = game
            break
        printBoard()
        if(players == 1):
            moveSquare(2, 1)
        if(players == 2):
            moveSquare(2, 0)
        game = checkForWin()
        if(game > 0):
            win = game + 1
            break
    if(win == 1):
        print("\nX Wins!")
    if(win == 2):
        print("\nO Wins!")
    if(win == 3):
        print("\n The game is a draw!")
    quit = gameOver()
exit()
```

I am interested in the following points about my code:

- How can I make my code smaller and more optimized?
- The game displays "O Wins" instead of "The game is a draw!" and I'm not sure why.
- How can I sanitize input to prevent crashes if a string is entered instead of an integer (for example when choosing a square on the board)?
- Any additional points to improve my code or general tips that will help me become a better Python programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random

board = [0]*9
```

Having global variables that change is considered a bad idea. You'd be better off putting this variable and the methods inside a class.

```
def resetBoard():
    for index, i in enumerate(board):
        board[index] = 0
```

You could also do `board[:] = [0] * 9`

```
def printBoard():
    counter = 0
```

In python you rarely need to keep track of counters like this

```
    s = ""
```

In python, you should avoid building strings by adding different pieces together

```
    print("|-----|-----|-----|")
    for index, i in enumerate(board):
        s += "|  "
        if(board[index] == 0):
```

The point of enumerate is that `i` is the value in board. Use it rather then refetching it here.

```
            s += str(index)
        if(board[index] == 1):
            s+= "x"
        if(board[index] == 2):
            s += "o"
        s += "  "
```

By building the string this way its hard to follow exactly what the string is.

```
        counter += 1
        if(counter == 3):
```

Instead of making the counter use `if index % 3 == 2:' Also you don't need the parens

```
            s += "|"
            print(s)
            print("|-----|-----|-----|")
            s = ""
            counter = 0
```

Your whole algorithm here is rendered more complicated because you are iterating over cells rather the rows. Your algorithm would be much more natural with rows

```
def getPlayers():
    return input("1 or 2 Players?")
```

Shouldn't this return an int, not a string?

```
def moveSquare(xOro, ai):
```

variable names are recommended to follow x_or_o as a naming convetion

```
    square = 0
    flag = 0
```

If this is a boolean flag, use False not 0

```
    while(board[square] != 0 or flag == 0):
```

No need for the parens around the while expression

```
        if(ai == 0):
```

Again use True/False for boolean flags. No need for parens

```
            if(xOro == 1):
                square = eval(input("Choose a square to place X: "))
            if(xOro == 2):
                square = eval(input("Choose a square to place O: "))
```

Avoid magic numbers like 1 and 2 to denote X and O. In this case, I'd probably pass 'x' or 'o' strings.

```
        if(ai == 1):
```

Use an else:

```
            square = random.randint(0, 8)
        flag = 1
```

Flag is really terrible variable name because I don't know what it means. Boolean flags are usually an ugly solution

```
    board[square] = xOro
    print("\n\n")

def checkForWin():
    if(board[0] == board[1] and board[1] == board[2] and board[2] != 0):
        return 1
```

Don't use magic numbers like that. Instead create some global constants to return or something

```
    if(board[3] == board[4] and board[4] == board[5] and board[5] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[6] == board[7] and board[7] == board[8] and board[8] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[0] == board[3] and board[3] == board[6] and board[6] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[1] == board[4] and board[4] == board[7] and board[7] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[2] == board[5] and board[5] == board[8] and board[8] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[0] == board[4] and board[4] == board[8] and board[8] != 0):
        return 1
    if(board[2] == board[4] and board[4] == board[6] and board[6] != 0):
        return 1
```

A lot duplication here.

```
    for index, i in enumerate(board):
        if(i  == 0):
            break
        if(index == 8):
            return 2
    return 0

def gameOver():
    return eval(input("\nPress 0 and then ENTER to play again!"))
```

Eval is a bit dangerous because the user can put in anything they want.

```
# Main
```

You should your main logic in a function

```
random.seed()
quit = 0
while(quit == 0):
```

Make quite a boolean variable

```
    players = 0
    win = 0
    while(players != 1 and players != 2):
        players = eval(getPlayers())
    resetBoard()
    game = 0 #game = 1 when game is finished
```

Game becoming 1 when the game is finished seems backwards

```
    while(game == 0): #game loop
        printBoard()
        moveSquare(1, 0)
        game = checkForWin()
        if(game > 0):
            win = game
            break
```

Not much point checking game == 0 above if you are just going to break anyways

```
        printBoard()
        if(players == 1):
            moveSquare(2, 1)
        if(players == 2):
            moveSquare(2, 0)
        game = checkForWin()
        if(game > 0):
            win = game + 1
            break
```

See how the two parts of the loop are very similar? Suggests that you should get rid of the duplication.

```
    if(win == 1):
        print("\nX Wins!")
    if(win == 2):
        print("\nO Wins!")
    if(win == 3):
        print("\n The game is a draw!")
    quit = gameOver()
```

Having gameOver() return whether or not you should quit seems confusing. The name doesn't suggest that

```
exit()
```

Not much point in calling quit, the program is about to terminate anyways

And just to demonstrate how I'd do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random

WINNING_LINES = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [5, 6, 7],

    [0, 3, 5],
    [1, 4, 6],
    [2, 5, 7],

    [0, 4, 7],
    [2, 4, 5]
]

STALEMATE = '!'

class TicTacToe(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [' '] * 9

    def print(self):
        # make a copy of the board
        cells = self.board[:] 

        # put a digit in every blank cell
        for index, cell in enumerate(cells):
            if cell == ' ':
                cells[index] = str(index)

        # put spaces around the cells
        cells = [' %s ' % cell for cell in cells]

        # print the actual board
        print('|---|---|---|')
        for start in range(0, 9, 3):
            row = cells[start:start+3]
            print('|', '|'.join(row), '|', sep = '')
            print('|---|---|---|')

    def move_square(self, player, ai):
        square = -1
        while square < 0 or square >= 9 or self.board[square] != ' ':
            if ai:
                square = random.randrange(9)
            else:
                question = "Choose a square to place {}:".format(player.upper())
                square_text = input(question)
                print(square_text)
                try:
                    square = int(square_text)
                except ValueError:
                    # user didn't enter a number
                    square = -1
        self.board[square] = player
        print("\n\n")

    def status(self):
        # check for a win
        for a, b, c in WINNING_LINES:
            if self.board[a] == self.board[b] and self.board[b] == self.board[c] and self.board[a] != ' ':
                return self.board[a]

        if not any(cell == ' ' for cell in self.board):
            return STALEMATE
        return ' '

def get_players():
    while True:
        text = input("1 or 2 players")
        try:
            value = int(text)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            if 0 < value < 3:
                return value




def play_again():
    return input("\nPress 0 and then ENTER to play again!") == '0'

GAME_OVER_MESSAGES = {
    'X' : 'X wins!',
    'O' : 'O wins!',
    '!' : 'The game is a draw!'
}

def main():

    while True:

        # create a list to denote whether
        # a player is AI
        ai_players = [False, False]
        if get_players() == 1:
            ai_players[1] = True


        tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe()
        player_turn = 0
        player_codes = 'XY'
        while tic_tac_toe.status() == ' ':
            tic_tac_toe.print()
            tic_tac_toe.move_square(player_codes[player_turn], ai_players[player_turn])
            player_turn = (player_turn + 1) % 2

        print(GAME_OVER_MESSAGES[tic_tac_toe.status()])

        if not play_again():
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of comments on general style:

```
while(players != 1 and players != 2):
    players = eval(getPlayers())
```

I would expect getPlayers() to get the player information and do any error handling.
Thus in the main loop this should just be a single call:

```
players = getPlayers()
```

You have lots of places where you do the same thing in two different ways:

```
    if(players == 1):
        moveSquare(2, 1)
    if(players == 2):
        moveSquare(2, 0)
```

You can simplify this as

```
    moveSquare(2, players - 1)
```

Same sort of thing here:

```
if(win == 1):
    print("\nX Wins!")
if(win == 2):
    print("\nO Wins!")
if(win == 3):
    print("\n The game is a draw!")
```

Can be much neater like this:

```
print(result[win])   # Now just define the result array.
```

Your problem with printing the wrong thing on a draw is here:

```
    if(game > 0):
        win = game
        break
```

Notice this is different from your second check here

```
    game = checkForWin()
    if(game > 0):
        win = game + 1
        break
```

So checkForWin() returns 0 for no winner 1 for winner and 2 for a draw.
The first check above will result in win being 1 or 2 even for a draw, while the second check will result in 2 or 3 (which is probably correct).

What you really want to do is make checkForWin() return the result you are looking for.

```
0:  for no winner
1:  for player one
2:  for player two
3:  for a draw.
```

You can even optimize checkForWin() by passing in the player that made the last move and the position they played in (as the winning move will include their last move).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random


# Put the ID of the square in each square for easy printing.
# We will put 'X' or 'O' in the square as we make each move
def resetBoard(board):
    for index, i in enumerate(board):
        board[index] = index

# Print the board
def printBoard(board):
    s = ""
    for index, i in enumerate(board):
        s += "|  %s  " % i
        if((index % 3) == 2):
            print("|-----|-----|-----|\n%s|" % s)
            s = ""
    print("|-----|-----|-----|")

# Function to get the human mve
def humanMove(playerToMove, board):

    print "Human Move (%s)" % playerToMove
    return eval(raw_input("Choose a square to place %s: " % playerToMove))

# Function to get the AI move
def aiMove(playerToMove, board):

    print "AI Move (%s)" % playerToMove
    return random.randint(0, 8)

def moveSquare(playerToMove, players, board):
    # Get the move from the cuttrny player
    # Note this passes weather they are an 'X' or an 'O' 
    # as a parameter.
    FirstTry    = False
    square      = 0
    while(board[square] == 'X' or board[square] == 'O' or FirstTry):
        square  = players[playerToMove](playerToMove, board)
        FirstTry    = False;
    board[square] = playerToMove            # Puts an 'X' or an 'O' on the board
    print("\n\n")

#
# This function returns a dictionary with move move functions.
# So on 'X' move call the result{'X'} function to get a move
# So we have to decide how to fill the dictionary based on user input.
def getPlayers():
    players = 0;
    while players != 1 and players != 2:
        players = input("1 or 2 Players?")

    if players == 2:
       # Two players so both elements call the humanMove function
       return {'X': humanMove, 'O': humanMove}

    if players == 1:
        human      = '?'
        while human != 'X' and human != 'O':
            human      = raw_input("Do you want to play X or O");
        if human == 'X':
            # Human is playing X ai is playing O so functions set appropriately.
            return {'X': humanMove, 'O': aiMove}
        else:
            return {'X': aiMove, 'O': humanMove}


#
# Return 'X' for winner is X
# Return 'O' for winner is O
# Return 'D' for a draw
# Return 'R' for game is still running.
def checkForWin(board):
    if(board[0] == board[1] and board[1] == board[2] and board[2] != 0):
        return board[0]
    if(board[3] == board[4] and board[4] == board[5] and board[5] != 0):
        return board[3]
    if(board[6] == board[7] and board[7] == board[8] and board[8] != 0):
        return board[6]
    if(board[0] == board[3] and board[3] == board[6] and board[6] != 0):
        return board[0]
    if(board[1] == board[4] and board[4] == board[7] and board[7] != 0):
        return board[1]
    if(board[2] == board[5] and board[5] == board[8] and board[8] != 0):
        return board[2]
    if(board[0] == board[4] and board[4] == board[8] and board[8] != 0):
        return board[0]
    if(board[2] == board[4] and board[4] == board[6] and board[6] != 0):
        return board[2]

    # No winner yet
    # decide if the game is still running.
    for index, i in enumerate(board):
        if(i  != 'X' or i != 'O'):
            return 'R'

    # No empty squares so it must be a draw.
    return 'D'

def gameOver():
    return raw_input("\nPress 0 and then ENTER to play again!")

# Main
random.seed()
quit = "0"
board = [0]*9

while(quit == "0"):
    resetBoard(board)
    winner          = 'R'
    players         = getPlayers()
    playerOrder     = ['X', 'O']
    currentPlayer   = 0;
    while True:
        printBoard(board)

        moveSquare(playerOrder[currentPlayer], players, board)
        winner = checkForWin(board)
        if winner != 'R':
            break

        currentPlayer   = (currentPlayer + 1) % 2

    result  = { 'X': "X Wins!",'O': "O Wins!",  'D': "The game is a draw!"}
    print "\n%s\n" % result[winner];

    quit = gameOver()
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the second argument to moveSquare. The first argument is the player number. The second number indicates whether or not this is an AI player.